# How to run a Mathematica program using command line on windows?

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have to run some Mathematica programs on a remote computer running the [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP) operating system. However, I do not know how to run the program using the command line on this system.

What do I need to do in order to run Mathematica code remotely on Windows XP?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingATextBasedInterface.html

Comment: Thank you. But this link does not include the way on windows. I know how to do on Linux.

Comment: Try `MathKernel` http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathKernel.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As indicated in the documentation, one can access the *Mathematica* kernel from the command prompt using the command [`math`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/math.html) in Unix/Linux and [`MathKernel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/MathKernel.html) from Mac OS X/ Windows.

If the `MathKernel` command is not in your `PATH` variable, you can try one of several things:

1. Enter the full pathname as part of the command
2. Add `MathKernel` as a `PATH` variable using the [instructions](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) appropriate to your version of Windows. This will generally involve (a) right-clicking on the **My Computer** icon from the desktop and choosing **Properties**, then (b) clicking on a tab or button with the word **Advanced** in its label (it’s the **Advanced System Settings** link in Vista and later), and then  (c) choosing the **Environment Variables** option.
3. Using the command prompt, navigate to the directory in Windows that stores the *Mathematica* kernel executable, as described in [this page in the *Mathematica* documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html).

[This documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StandaloneWolframLanguageKernels.html) collects all the relevant commands together.

There are several relevant tutorials in the documentation, including on [use of the text-based interface](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingATextBasedInterface.html) and [a listing of command-line options and environment variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemSessions.html).

Comment: I have tried MathKernel in cmd on Windows. But it said thtat something like "MatheKernel is not a command". How to install the command?

Comment: @wxg `MathKernel` is not in your `PATH` variable. Enter the full path name and it will work.

Comment: @Ajasja I have tried as you suggested. Can you tell me how to add MathKernel in the PATH variables? So I can simplely use MathKernel.

Comment: @wxg here you go: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm also you have to restart `cmd` so that the changes will take effect.

Comment: @wxg You could also navigate to the directory in Windows where the executable is stored, C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0, according to http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaFileOrganization.html

Comment: Thanks @Ajasja and image_doctor - I have added your suggestions and made the post community wiki in recognition of the joint contributions.

Comment: @Verbeia You needn't have made this a community wiki: you did all the work. Two comments hardly count as joint contributions:)

Comment: @Ajasja - I always count the contribution as how much effort it would have taken *me* to work out. I'm no Windows export, so those bits would have taken me a while. I got 60 points out of it before I switched it, which is plenty given the kind of answer it is.

Comment: @Verbeia most kind of you.

Comment: As of September 2015, a number of the links to Wolfram pages are no longer valid.  I tried to find the correct links to update the answer, but failed miserably.

Comment: WolframKernel aka MathKernel page with command line keys lives [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/WolframKernel.html)