# How to use deep clones in Mathematica

Tags: programming, kernel, kernel-startup

Is there a way to use deep clones in Mathematica?

Maybe by making lots of different kernels. In order to execute multiple notebooks I need more than one kernel, is there a way to make them using C# code?

Comment: What do you mean by "deep clone"?

Comment: @C.E. I edited my question

Comment: Still not nearly enough info.

Comment: @Jan Notice that you have not addressed the key question here, i.e. what is a "deep clone"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to make a variable available for many threads in parallel computing, you should check out [`DistributeDefinitions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html).

If you need parallel processing, you should first try built-in parallel functions like [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) before running many copies of the whole *Mathematica*.

In case you need dedicated kernels called from external software, consider running Wolfram Language scripts (`.m` files instead of Notebooks `.nb`)
with dedicated kernels [invoked from the command line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/how-to-run-a-mathematica-program-using-command-line-on-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1).

If you really need to talk to a live kernel from external applications, there is [MathLink](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3710/).

If by *deep clone* you just mean to have another independent variable with the same value, then almost all variables in Mathematica can be considered deep copies (you do not need to know how the underlying memory is actually handled for you by the kernel) (an exception is [delayed evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)).